# Integration Awesomomium in Unity - RenderBuffer is an ambiguous reference between UnityEngine.RenderBuffer and AwesomiumMono.RenderBuffer

Tags: unity-game-engine, awesomium

I have to integrate Awesomium in Unity 3d. I have went over the steps defined in

http://labs.awesomium.com/unity3d-integration-tutorial-part-1/

But when i have to drag the webTexture.cs over the player object its giving below error.

Assets/WebTexture.cs(226,13): error CS0104: `RenderBuffer' is an ambiguous reference between`UnityEngine.RenderBuffer' and `AwesomiumMono.RenderBuffer'

Kindly assist!

Thanks,
Vandana

Comment: Done, I have fixed my own. In WebTexture.cs (which is provided by Awesomium) has ambiguity in Reference. Pass  AwesomiumMono.RenderBuffer _rBuffer = webView.Render();

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed my own

In WebTexture.cs (Class file provided by Awesomium) has ambiguity in Reference.

Instead of 
** RenderBuffer _rBuffer = webView.Render();**
Call
 AwesomiumMono.RenderBuffer _rBuffer = webView.Render();

It will fix and load you web container.